# Chrome developer tools - any way to see what CSS is used by the current page?

Tags: css, browser, google-chrome

Using Google's Chrome Developer Tools, I sometimes run audits on my code to see how it is coming together. One of the suggestions those tools always make is "Removed Unused CSS Rules". Clicking on the arrow then shows a usually huge list of the CSS rules that are not being used by the current page.

Is there a way to see a list of what CSS rules ARE being used by the current page?

Comment: I don't believe the Chrome Dev Tools have a way to do this, no. Someone might have written a separate tool to do it, though.

Comment: I reckon Google Page Speed will tell you the unused CSS rules. Maybe that's the opposite of what you are asking for. At least that how it works in Firefox.

Comment: @Michael - yes, it is the opposite. Chrome tools already show a list of unused CSS.

Answer (score 3):

I know this may be a tad late but in case someone else stumbles across this like I did and is also curious I found the **Dust-Me Selectors add-on for firefox** will tell you both the used and unused selectors on the page for each stylesheet used.

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

Press CTRL-SHIFT-J to access Chrome's dev tools. There you can choose resources tab, choose to enable them on the left and refresh the page if necessary. It will show all loaded files, including stylesheets.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question neXib. I'm asking how to find out specific CSS rules are being used by the current page, not which stylesheets are loaded.

Comment: Ah sorry. But it's sensible to show styles not used, as they don't exist in the stylesheets, but showing which ones ARE used will be confusing to use because of the hierarchy, so to me it wouldn't make sense to show it. If it says style li.horse is used but later you have li.horse .mane defined that won't be very usable.

Answer (score 0):

The developer tools are open source so you can create a patch.
http://dev.bootstraponline.com/2011/11/automatically-remove-unused-css-rules.html

snipp

```
//=== modified file 'AuditRules.js'
if (!testedSelectors[rule.selectorText] || foundSelectors[rule.selectorText])
{
    usedCss += "\n" + rule.selectorText + " {" + rule.style.cssText + "}\n";
    continue;
}
//...
// Save only used css rules.
InspectorFrontendHost.saveAs("used.css", usedCss);
```